# Conditionally add disabled attribute in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a disabled ngBootstrap datepicker. How can I disable this conditionally based on the value of a variable I have, `hasExistingEnrollmentPeriods`?

I've tried `disabled="hasExistingEnrollmentPeriods"` but that always sets disabled to true even when the expression is false.

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY" name="effecDate" ngbDatepicker #ed="ngbDatepicker"
  (click)="ed.toggle(); DetectChange()" (ngModelChange)="onSelectEffectiveDate($event)" formControlName="effectiveDate" disabled>
  <div class="input-group-append">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="ed.toggle()" type="button">
        <i class="fal fa-calendar-alt"></i>
     </button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `[disabled]`, not `disabled`.

- `disabled="hasExistingEnrollmentPeriods"` means `assign string value "hasExistingEnrollmentPeriods" to "disabled" attribute`.
- `[disabled]="hasExistingEnrollmentPeriods"` means `assign value of "hasExisstingEnrollmentPeriods" to "disabled" attribute.`.

Answer (score 3):

Use Angular [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#property-binding-property) with the [brackets notation](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#remember-the-brackets) to make sure that the parameter is evaluated as an expression:

```
[disabled]="hasExistingEnrollmentPeriods"
```